# Nice validation if the list is null

Tags: java

I have an object with several lists

```
public class Contribution<T extends MovieRequest> {
    private Set<T> elementsToAdd;
    private Set<T> elementsToUpdate;
    private Set<Integer> numbersToDelete;
}
```

This object is sent to the method. There I operate on these lists.

```
    public void correctOtherTitle(
            final Contribution<OtherTitle> contribution
    ) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        contribution.getElementsToAdd().forEach(otherTitle -> {
             ...
        });
        contribution.getNumbersToDelete().forEach(number -> {
             ...
        });
        contribution.getElementsToUpdate().forEach(otherTitleToUpdate -> {
             ...
        });
    }
```

The problem is that there is no need to complete all the lists and some of them may be null. And then throws a `NullPointerException` exception.
Of course, it is possible to make a condition `if`, but it does not look aesthetically.

```
if(contribution.getElementsToAdd() !- null) {    
       contribution.getElementsToAdd().forEach(otherTitle -> {
             ...
        });
}
```

It looks fatal. Do you have an idea how to do it better?

Comment: Maybe just prevent the possibility of them being `null` in the first place?  You have a getter, which implies you have a setter too, which ought to allow you to set up the appropriate invariants.

Comment: If you need to test for `null` to avoid NPE, you test for `null`.  This is part of the language.  Code has to have more than streamlined "happy paths" to be usable and robust.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid not null check with explicit `if` , you could change the types of the `Contribution` class fields to `Optional` that wrap the actual data :

```
public class Contribution<T extends MovieRequest> {
    private Optional<Set<T>> elementsToAdd;
    private Optional<Set<T>> elementsToUpdate;
    private Optional<Set<Integer>> numbersToDelete;
}
```

and adapt getters consequently.

In this way, you could use `Optional.ifPresent(Consumer<? super T> consumer)` that spares an explicit not null check :

```
contribution.getElementsToAdd().ifPresent(otherTitle -> {
     otherTitle.forEach(m -> ...);
});
```

It is not necessary very elegant either.
 However, it reduces code duplication without introducing intermediary variables (that may create side effect).
Getter methods are indeed invoked once.

Comment: I'd argue that this doesn't add very much in this case - there's already a way to represent "nothing to add/update/delete", i.e. an empty set.  And if the OP is worried about the client blindly/accidentally setting these fields to null, then `Optional` won't protect against that.

Comment: I agree it doesn't add very much. Not repeating `contribution.getElementsToAdd()`  before and after the check is however a good thing.  About the OP requirement, we can read : "The problem is that there is **no need to complete all the lists** and some of them may be null".

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that there is no need to complete all the lists and some of them may be null.

I'd argue that you should fix the root problem, rather than work around it.  Why can these sets be null?  You already have a "safe" way to indicate that there's nothing to add/delete/update - an empty set.  So if these sets are under your control (the fact that they are `private` and you have getters implies this), then you should enforce that invariant.

For example, maybe your `Contribution` class could look like this:

```
public class Contribution<T extends MovieRequest> {
    private Set<T> elementsToAdd = new HashSet<>();
    // ... same for elementsToUpdate / numbersToDelete ...

    public Set<T> getElementsToAdd() {
        return Collections.ummodifiableSet(elementsToAdd);
    }

    public void addElementToAdd(T element) {
        elementsToAdd.add(element);
    }
}
```

This pattern involves a fair amount of boilerplate.  But code generators such as [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/) help a great deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut to check for not null, but you could implement a constructor on the Contribution class and initialize the sets to empty sets.

Also,  if the code matters to you, I may  suggest you to invest your efforts in trying to push the logic of the correctOtherTitle function into the Contribution class,  because passing and object to a method that manipulates the object smells like an  anemic domain.

Comment: "Anaemic domains" may have been a concern like 15 years ago.  But separating out a behaviour-less data model from the actors is an increasingly common pattern now.